# React: How to re-render component to show new data after API POST?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, post, state

I'm pretty new to React and working on a project for learning purposes. I've setup an express back-end with MongoDB.

I have three components:

1. Parent Component -> imports the two child components and passes "update" function as a Prop to the view component
2. Child Component One (view) -> Uses async(ComponentDidUpdate) to make a .get request to my back-end to fetch data and displays it in a table
3. Child Component Two (create) -> A form which has a save button. When save is
   clicked it makes a .post to my back-end and stores the values in mongo

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to "refresh" or "re-render" my **view** component after a new task has been created. I'm only able to see the newly created task by manually reloading the page.

Dumbed-down version of my code (my source is mess from trying so many different things).

**PARENT COMPONENT**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ViewTasks from '../ViewTasks/ViewTasks';
import CreateTask from '../CreateTask/CreateTask';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  }
  
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getTasks();
  }
  
  
  getData = async() => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("/tasks");
      const data = res.data.data;
      const tasks = data.map((task) => { // did this to use MaterialUI sortable table - works ok
        return {...task}
      }
      // Set the state
      this.setState({
        data: tasks 
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  
  
  render() {
    return (
      <ViewTask tasks={this.state.data}/>
      <CreateTask refreshTasks={this.getData} />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**VIEW COMPONENT (child to Dashboard above)**

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class ViewData extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const tasks = this.props.tasks
    return (
      <Paper>
        <Table>
           // map through tasks and display in table
        </Table>
      </Paper>
    )
  }
}
```

**CREATE COMPONENT (child to Dashboard, sibling to VIEW)**

```js
// this component is a MaterialUI Dialog

import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class createTask extends React.Component {
  state = {
    task: {
      authorName: '',
      taskName: ''
    }
  }

  handleSave = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await axios.post('/task', {
        authorName: this.state.task.authorName,
        taskName: this.state.task.taskName
      })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    this.props.getData();  // invoke the getData function from Dashboard page to get a new list of tasks
  }
  
  onAuthorNameChange = (name) => ({target: {value}}) => { 
    this.setState({
      task: {
        ...this.state.task,        
        [name]: value
      }
    })
  }

  onTaskNameChange = (name) => ({target: {value}}) => {
    this.setState({
      task: {
        ...this.state.task,
        [name]: value
      }
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you have all data in `const tasks` in View Component? Can you print and check it?

Comment: I would throw a loading flag into your setstates. Then in your JSX throw a conditional loading operator at the top of your return.  The jsx would update once the change to state occurs.

Answer (score 0):

What about this.  Can't really test, but awaiting results and only doing something when results actually come in is probably the way to go.

```
try {
  const res = await axios.get("/tasks")
  .then(
  if(res.data){
  const data = res.data.data;
  const tasks = data.map((task) => { // did this to use MaterialUI sortable table - works ok
    return {...task}
  }}
  // Set the state
  this.setState({
    data: tasks 
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
```

}
  }